# What does the Efficiency field in the Karate output table represent? Efficiency compared to what?

Tags: output, karate

I was wondering as to what the Efficiency field in the Karate output table in the console represent.
I see it has a value of 0.98 after i execute my tests, so it is 98% efficient. But compared to what?

Seems no one had this question earlier i suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple search through the source (https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/9992eaf8d7b9dd637477a0970de1a1187b820fc2/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/Results.java#L163)

tells us that:

```
public double getEfficiency() {
    return timeTakenMillis / (getElapsedTime() * threadCount);
}
```

If I understood the metric correctly, it means how efficiently we are using threads. If `efficiency == 1` then all threads are fully used.

The metric doesn't give any meaningful information unless you have more than 1 thread.

EDIT: more information on the stats: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62958327/143475

Comment: My baseline, `T=2` I got `elapsed=2.15s`, `efficiency=0.74`. Yet, when `T=4` I got `elapsed=1.43`, `efficiency=0.59`. Even though I executed the tests in less time, my efficiency was worse.

I think it tells how you how much threads are helping lower that execution time.